# PHP how to avoid mixed letter-number when extracting chunks of numbers from string

Tags: php, regex

I'm writing a **PHP** function to extract numeric ids from a string like:

```
$test = '123_123_Foo'
```

At first I took two different approaches, one with `preg_match_all()`:

```
$test2 = '123_1256_Foo';
preg_match_all('/[0-9]{1,}/', $test2, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]); // Result: 'Array ( [0] => 123 [1] => 1256 )'
```

and other with `preg_replace()` and `explode()`:

```
$test = preg_replace('/[^0-9_]/', '', $test);
$output = array_filter(explode('_', $test));
print_r($output); // Results: 'Array ( [0] => 123 [1] => 1256 )'
```

Any of them works well as long as the string does not content mixed letters and numbers like:

```
$test2 = '123_123_234_Foo2'
```

The evident result is **Array ( [0] => 123 [1] => 1256 [2] => 2 )**

So I wrote another regex to get rid off of mixed strings:

```
$test2 = preg_replace('/([a-zA-Z]{1,}[0-9]{1,}[a-zA-Z]{1,})|([0-9]{1,}[a-zA-Z]{1,}[0-9]{1,})|([a-zA-Z]{1,}[0-9]{1,})|([0-9]{1,}[a-zA-Z]{1,})|[^0-9_]/', '', $test2);
$output = array_filter(explode('_', $test2));
print_r($output); // Results: 'Array ( [0] => 123 [1] => 1256 )'
```

The problem is evident too, more complicated paterns like **Foo2foo12foo1** would pass the filter. And here's where I got a bit stuck.

Recap:

- Extract a variable ammount of chunks of numbers from string.
- The string contains at least 1 number, and may contain other numbers
  and letters separated by underscores.
- Only numbers not preceded or followed by letters must be extracted.
- Only the numbers in the first half of the string matter.

Since only the first half is needed I decided to split in the first occurrence of letter or mixed number-letter with `preg_split()`:

```
$test2 = '123_123_234_1Foo2'
$output = preg_split('/([0-9]{1,}[a-zA-Z]{1,})|[^0-9_]/', $test, 2);
preg_match_all('/[0-9]{1,}/', $output[0], $matches);
print_r($matches[0]); // Results: 'Array ( [0] => 123 [1] => 123 [2] => 234 )'
```

The point of my question is if is there a simpler, safer or more efficient way to achieve this result.

Comment: So you want to extract only the underscore-delimited substrings that are entirely numeric and reject everything else?

Comment: Something like this? https://eval.in/886873 - I'm not posting an answer because I am not 100% if I understand the wording of your question.

Comment: `$test2  = "123_123_234_1Foo2";
$ints = array_filter(explode('_', $test2 ), 'is_numeric');
var_dump($ints);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to split an underscore-delimited string, and filter out any substrings that are not numeric. If so, this can be achieved without regex, with [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and [`ctype_digit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php); e.g:

```
<?php

$str = '123_123_234_1Foo2';

$digits = array_filter(explode('_', $str), function ($substr) {
  return ctype_digit($substr);
});

print_r($digits);
```

This yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 123
    [1] => 123
    [2] => 234
)
```

Note that `ctype_digit()`:

> Checks if all of the characters in the provided string are numerical.

So `$digits` is still an array of strings, albeit numeric.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: @DarraghEnright `$digits = array_filter(explode('_', $str ), 'ctype_digit');` you are able to put the function as second argument of array_filter

Comment: @EmilioGort - Absolutely! This is true, and since it's a one-liner making it quite concise/readable. I know about it but I prefer writing an explicit callback - I guess that's just my style :) It should be noted that a callback is quite a bit faster than passing the callable as a string. However, I'll be first to admit that "argument" (if you'll excuse the pun) is a micro-optimisation! ;)

Answer (score 2):

## Use [strtok](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php)

Regex isn't a magic bullet, and there are FAR simpler fixes for your problem, especially considering you're trying to split on a delimiter.

Any of the following approaches would be cleaner, and more maintainable, and the `strtok()` approach would *probably* perform better:

1. Use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to create and loop through an array, checking each value.
2. Use [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) to do the same, but with more a adaptable approach.
3. Use strtok, as it is designed exactly for this use-case.

**Basic exmple for your case:**

```
function strGetInts(string $str, str $delim) {
    $word = strtok($str, $delim);

    while (false !== $word) {
        if (is_integer($word) {
            yield (int) $word;
        }
        $word = strtok($delim);
    }   
}

$test2 = '123_1256_Foo';

foreach(strGetInts($test2, '_-') as $key {
    print_r($key);
}
```

**Note:** the second argument to strtok is string containing ANY delimiter to split the string on. Thus, my example will group results into strings separated by underscores or dashes.

**Additional Note:** If and only if the string only needs to be split on a single delimiter (underscore only), a method using `explode` will likely result in better performance. For such a solution, see the other answer in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46937452/1589379 .

Answer (score 2):

Getting just the numeric part of the string after the explode

```
$test2  = "123_123_234_1Foo2";
$digits = array_filter(explode('_', $test2 ), 'ctype_digit');
var_dump($digits);
```

Result

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "123"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "123"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "234"
}
```

Comment: `is_numeric()` will return `true` if it determines that a string is floating-point number. Previously to PHP 7.* it also returned `true` for strings that could represent hex and binary numbers. This may not be an issue for the OP but it's worth flagging.

Comment: Note: this the best option **IFF** underscore is the _only_ delimiter the string should be split on. Should the string need to be split on other delimiters as well ( _ - / \ ), etc, strtok is the better option.

Comment: `is_numeric()` is not reliable for this task.  Watch it break: https://3v4l.org/Ro5gP

Answer (score 0):

This task is simply accomplished with a single `preg_match_all()` call.

Use a pattern that matches one or more digits which is:

1. preceded by the start of the string or an underscore and is
2. followed by an underscore or the end of the string.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/AW2Fi))

```
$test2 = '123_123_234_1Foo2';
preg_match_all('/(?<=^|_)\d+(?=_|$)/', $test2, $m);
var_export($m[0]);
```